# How to create pie chart from 1 column with duplicates

Tags: microsoft-excel-2010

I'm trying to create a pie chart from only one column which has duplicates, I want it to display the name of the item and how many duplicates there are of it. Se below

```
Apple
Mac
Windows
Apple
Mac
Apple
Mac
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This can be done by a pivot table, then a pie chart.

1. Add a cell `Fruits` above your first entry
2. `Insert` -> `Pivot Table`
3. Select range of all the cells

[image]

4. Move "OS" to `ROWS` and `VALUES`

[image]

[image]

5. Select the pivot table, then `Insert` -> `Pie Chart`

[image]